# Guest user CRUD permissions. Remove from Sandbox or Production as well?

Tags: force.com-sites

On November 30, 2018,Salesforce discovered that guest user CRUD permissions in your Salesforce Sites and Communities could have potentially allowed unauthenticated guest users to retrieve information in Salesforce records including, but not limited to, the Account and Contact objects.

Starting on December 14, 2018, Salesforce began to re-mediate the issue by removing those permissions.

Is this permission is removed from sandbox or production as well ?

Comment: Do you have any link for this? Or it was specific to your org?

Comment: Its specific to my org AND It is not working in Production also.